# Как узнать ближайшее существующее локальное время?

Tags: python, часовые-пояса

С помощью [pytz](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) я могу проверить, существует ли указанное локальное время в указанном часовом поясе:

```
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")
tz.localize(datetime(2011, 3, 27, 2, 30, 0), is_dst=None)
# pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2011-03-27 02:30:00
```

После того, как я узнал, что интересующее меня время не существует, я хочу узнать, какое ближайшее локальное время существует. Другими словами, я хочу получить один из двух таких объектов (а лучше оба сразу):

```
datetime(2011, 3, 27, 1, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSK+3:00:00 STD>)
datetime(2011, 3, 27, 3, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSK+4:00:00 STD>)
```

Есть ли способ более эффективный, чем ручной перебор дат по минутам?)

(В принципе использование модуля [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) меня тоже устроит, но в его документации я пока что не обнаружил, как сделать нужные мне штуки)

Comment: В доке `pytz` там рекомендуют, как можно просто обойти это ограничение и всё-равно создать локальное время именно такое, хотя оно и не существует. Вам реально это вот нужно для чего-то - ближайшее корректное локальное время?

Comment: @CrazyElf вообще, исходная задача — поделить диапазон даты на более мелкие диапазоны по указанным часам-минутам для последующей обработки каждого диапазона в отдельности. Однако если точка деления случайно попадает в несуществующее время (как 2:30 в этом примере), то нужно как-то это адекватно обработать (если втупую обойти ограничение, то это даст некорректный результат), вот я и пытаюсь что-нибудь придумать

Comment: А некорректный результат - это настолько прям плохо? Ну там на деньги кто-то попадёт или что? Просто опять же смотря что за задача. Если это машинное обучение на каких-то данных, то можно просто попробовать такие данные выкинуть и вряд ли это сильно повлияет на результаты, если остальных данных много.

Comment: @CrazyElf таки да, это связано с деньгами)

Comment: Предлагаю взять исходники, там есть список транзитов. Только нужно сообразить ещё он сам то в `UTC` или что. Мне кажется, на его основе можно будет сразу получить концы выпадающего диапазона, ну а там уже посмотреть - какой из них ближе. https://github.com/newvem/pytz/blob/master/pytz/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow.py Не исключаю, что это и из самого объекта таймзоны можно получить, если знать название переменной.

Comment: А, ну точно, вот они `list(zip(tz._utc_transition_times, tz._transition_info))` Судя по названию это таки `UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, предлагаю взять список транзитов:

```
list(zip(tz._utc_transition_times, tz._transition_info))
```

При выпадении эксепшена на `localize` нужно будет пробежаться по этому списку двоичным поиском и найти, в какой элемент этого списка ваш `datetime` попал.

После этого определить, что ближе к вашему `datetime` - начало этого диапазона или конец.

Что ближе - то и результат.

P.S. `zoneinfo` я не смотрел.

Comment: Если я не накосячил, то, действительно, задача решается условным однострочником `get_next_existent_date = lambda dt, tz: tz.normalize(tz._utc_transition_times[max(0, bisect.bisect_right(tz._utc_transition_times, dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) - 1)].replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))` (но надо будет подумать, бывают ли какие-нибудь граничные случаи, которые понадобится обработать особым образом)

Comment: Кстати, в этом списке информация [только до 2038 года](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/31). Видимо, есть примерно 15 лет, чтобы придумать, как реализовать то же самое через zoneinfo )

Comment: @andreymal Ну не факт, что дальше не будут этот список обновлять в библиотеке. Тем более, что изменения могут быть и в значения раньше 2038 года внесены российским законодательством в любой момент )